# Error inflating AppCompatRadioButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, android-appcompat

I have some problems using AppCompatRadioButton

In the xml preview appears this:

`The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1ff0034   at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCompoundButtonHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatCompoundButtonHelper.java:63)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton.<init>(AppCompatRadioButton.java:61)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton.<init>(AppCompatRadioButton.java:54)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)`

> Xml:`

```
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_g"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>


                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_mg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

                </RadioGroup>`
```

I have another RadioButton in my code and it's working fine. I only have the problem with those two

Comment: may be because the theme inherited in this layout causing this, Kindly check what theme you are using in the layout where your RadioButton is working

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. They're all in the same layout and I've just realised that in API 23 they're working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you use androidx then you should use in xml

> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/external_resource"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth_italic"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
                            android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

but looking in to error there is resource error

Comment: Hi Beyaz! My question was 3 years ago, and i'm not working with android anymore. So, i can't test if your answer it's right. Thank you anyway!